# Meaning of '-onomy', '-ology' and '-ography'

Tags: meaning, etymology

I have always wondered about the similarity of the two words

> **Astronomy** and **Astrology**

that describe two very different things but have their beginning in common and are sometimes confused in everyday language.
The linguistic difference (if one can say so) between them is only in the endings *'-onomy'* and *'-ology'*. Two further examples are

> **Topology** and **Topography**
>
> **Geology** and **Geography**

where now we have the endings *'-ology'* and *'-ography'*.

- What are the meanings of the different endings *'-onomy'*, *'-ology'* and *'-ography'* ?
- I would also be curious about whether it is a coincidence that *'-ology'* appears in all the examples above? Does it maybe have historical reasons?
- And furthermore, are there more such pairs to be found? (I can't think of any others)

Comment: economy, ecology; biology, biography; cardiography, cardiology; gastronomy, gastrology;

Comment: I thought examples might be useful.
geology: body of knowledge about the earth (rocks: where they are and why they are)
geography: writing about the earth (observations)
geometry: measurement (surveying)
geonomy: "...physical laws relating to the earth, including geology and physical geography ..." http://www.wordnik.com/words/geonomy
Thanks for the previous posts.

Comment: I've had this question for quite some time, and never thought it would attract so enlightening answers and comments.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The suffix **-logy** means a branch of learning, or study of a particular subject.

The suffix **-nomy** means a system of rules or laws, or body of knowledge of a particular subject.

These two are often intertwined as you might expect.

(Note that *-ology* and *-onomy* are alternate forms which include the connecting vowel *-o-*.)

The suffix **-graphy** refers to something written about a particular subject.

It's no coincidence that *-logy-* appears to be so common, as it refers to a wide variety of branches of study.

Another familiar suffix is **-metry** which refers to measurement, e.g. *geometry*, to continue your *geo-* theme.

Comment: Greek _ΓΡΆΦΩ_ /'grapʰɔ:/ 'write'; _ΛΌΓΟΣ_ /'logos/ 'word'; _ὊΝΟΜΑ_ /'onoma/ 'name; rule'. So _-ography_ means 'writing about', _ology_ means 'words about', and _-onomy_ means 'rules about'.

Comment: From:  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-rama?s=t

-rama: variant of -orama, occurring as the final element in compounds when the first element is disyllabic and does not end in -r,  used so that the entire word maintains the same number of syllables as panorama, Cinerama, and telerama.  
 
Word origin & History of -rama:  noun suffix meaning "spectacular display or instance of," 1824, abstracted from panorama, ultimately from Gk. horama "sight." [So it appears that -orama means "about sight," if Mr. Lawler is correct (which I assume he is).]

Comment: As an "armchair etymologist" I might have been tempted to suppose that *-nomy* had its origins in *nemein -> nomos -> name*. In which case arguably astronomers and astrologers have got their names mixed up, since the former really *do* study the stars in a meaningful sense. Astrologers are more concerned with assigning names to "accidental configurations" in the night sky that just happen to have a particular appearance from our vantage point.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, is _astrophysicist_ a preferred term these days? Just wonderin'

Comment: @Snubian: Probably. Astrology has been increasingly preoccupied with the *physics* of the universe ever since Fred Hoyle showed that it was apparently expanding. Not that they've exactly sussed out what's going on yet, but I doubt they'll find an answer just by *looking* through telescopes - it's all about constructing theories built on physics to *explain* what they see.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: And then there's _cosmology_, which wrestles back the _-logy_ from astrology.

Comment: Astrology is just another personality theory, like Freudianism or Myers-Briggs. It doesn't have anything to do with astronomy, except for calculating the positions of the planets in geocentric terms, which is very old astronomy. Anything else is theosophy and can be ignored profitably.

Comment: The name I like is _Economics_, which comes from Greek ὊΝΟΜΑ and also Greek _ϜΟΊΚΟΣ_ 'house, abode (Ϝ is the letter digamma, which was pronounced /w/ but dropped out of most Greek dialects, leaving only _ΟΊΚΟΣ_ as the root)', thus 'the laws of the household' . I.e, **All** Economics is Home Economics. _ϜΟΊΚΟΣ_ is cognate with Latin _vicus_ 'neighborhood, vicinity', from [PIE _*weik¹-_](http://web.archive.org/web/20080629184002/http://www.bartleby.com/61/roots/IE558.html), as are _village, diocese, parish,_ and _ecology_.

Comment: @JohnLawler: *Astronomy* and *economics* are not from *onoma* "name" but from *nomos* "law". And I don't think *onoma* can mean "rule". You knew I couldn't resist.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In your armchair etymology up there, you got the first two steps right, but the third one wrong. _Νέμω_ is indeed the same root as _νόμος_, and that is the root that underlies _-(o)nomy_. It is from a PIE root _*nem-_, which meant something like ‘grasp, allot, distribute, divide’ and is also found in the German word for ‘take’, _nehmen_ (and English _nimble_). It’s not related to _name_ at all, though, which is from PIE _*h₁nóh₃-mn̥-_ from the root _*h₁neh₃-_ and is _ὄνομα_ in Greek (Aeolic/Doric _ὄνῡμα_, Laconic _ἔνυμα_). They look alike in Greek, but they’re cheating.