# Osteopath vs Psychopath

Tags: etymology

Greek "Pathos" means "disease" or "suffering". In that sense "Psychopath" means "a person with an antisocial personality disorder". Originating from the same root "**Osteopath**" means "A therapist who manipulates the skeleton and muscles". Shouldn't it mean "Suffering of Skeleton and muscle"? And, Shouldn't "A therapist who manipulates the skeleton and muscles" be represented by "**Osteopathologist**"?

Greek "Logos" means "Science". Biology = "Study of living beings". Zoology= "Study of animals". Then why "Study of plants" is represented by "**Botany**". It should be "**Botanology**". Isn't it?

So, what are the explanations about the two words (1) Osteopath and (2) Botany?

Comment: I don't understand why you mention _logos._ Are you suggesting that _osteopath_ should be an _-ology_ word instead? It's simply short for “practitioner of osteopathic medicine” and is not parallel to _psychopath._ I'm not sure what you're really asking here though.

Comment: Related: [Meaning of '-onomy', '-ology' and '-ography'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116456/meaning-of-onomy-ology-and-ography). *Botanometry* FTW.

Comment: The whole of the answer is that language is as it is, not as somebody thinks it should be.

Comment: [osteopath](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=osteopath) is a backformation from [osteopathy](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=osteopath), [botany](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=botany) from [botanic](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=botanic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for -*path* I agree with user49727 (and so do [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-path) and [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/-path)), but I would like to add something about **botany**.

Merriam-Webster online states that:

> Origin of BOTANY
>   botanic botanical + 2-y
>   First Known Use: 1696

And their 2nd definition of suffix -y:

> -y
>
> **noun suffix** \same\
>   plural -ies
>
> Definition of -Y
>
> 1
>   :  state :  condition :  quality *beggary*
>
> 2
>   :  activity, place of business, or goods dealt with *chandlery* *laundry*
>
> 3
>   :  whole body or group *soldiery*
>
> Origin of -Y
>   Middle English -ie, from Anglo-French, from Latin -ia, from Greek -ia, -eia

Oxford Dictionaries Online has similar explanation for etymology of the word [botany](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/botany#botany__3)

> Origin
>
> Late 17th century: from earlier botanic (from French botanique, based on Greek botanikos, from botanē 'plant') + -y3.

And their 3rd definition of *-y*

> -y 3
>
> Pronunciation: /i/
>
> suffix
>
> Forming nouns:
>
> 1Denoting a state, condition, or quality: *honesty jealousy orthodoxy*
>
> 2Denoting an action or its result: *blasphemy victory*

*Botanic* and *botanical* are adjectives, and to name a science, or a branch of biology if you like, one needs a noun. There are other sciences which don't end in -*ology* and don't specifically have a suffix that denotes science or knowledge such as [physics](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/physics) or [chemistry](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=chemistry&allowed_in_frame=0).

Answer (score 3):

The suffix -*path* means [either](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=-path&searchmode=none) of the following:

1. person who practises a particular kind of medical treatment (back-formation from *-pathy*).
2. person who suffers from a particular disorder (derived from *pathos*)

As for *botany* the word is formed using a different rule to that of adding suffix -*logos*. It is formed by adding suffix -*y* as in *astronomy*.

Answer (score -1):

Greek "logos" means "word", "speech" &c.   So an "-ologist" is one who "speaks about" (i.e., studies and knows about things).

"Zoology" is from Greek "zoion "an animal," literally "a living being".   So "zoology" is the study of animals.   A zoo is where animals are.  The name "Zoe" means "life".

"Botanology" probably got shortened to "botany".  The stem "bota-" means "plant".